# How to set TextDirection to a flutter theme

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to set a TextDirection property to themeData in flutter to align all the text widgets in the app to be (TextDirection.rtl).

Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: `Directionality` ?

Comment: yes, of a text widgets

Comment: [Directionality](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Directionality-class.html)

Comment: yes I know it, but I want to use it in a theme of an app, not in every single Text widget

Comment: you use it at the root of your widget tree, not in every single Text widget

Comment: can you show me how please?

Comment: like any other widget: it has 2 required params: `TextDirection textDirection` and `Widget child` so pass `TextDirection.rtl` and the root child widget there

Comment: I understood, thanks a lot!

Comment: sure, your welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to set text direction for entire app, you may define that inside MaterialApp as below:

```
void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: Directionality(
        textDirection: TextDirection.rtl // or ltr,
        child: Demo(),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

[ref](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/62691)